# I don't understand how this char method works

Tags: java, char

How exactly does this method work? It's a method to shift characters. I dont understand how you can use 'a' to subtract from c. Is it all saved as numbers? And what does %=26 do in this situation?

```
private char shift(char c)
{
    int letter = c-'a';
    letter+= shift;
    letter %=26;
    return (char) ('a'+ letter);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters in C and Java can be handled as a very short number. But seen as a character it encodes one ASCII character.

```
letter %=26;
```

is simply a shorter expression for

```
letter = letter % 26;
```

% is the modulo operation and returns the reminder by division through the argument.

Your code does the following

```
private char shift(char c) {
    int letter = c-'a';          // calculate distance to 'a'
    letter+= shift;              // add some distance
    letter %=26;                 // handle overflow - if shifted behind 'z'
    return (char) ('a'+ letter); // apply calculated distance to 'a' to get output
                                 // and cast it to type char.
}
```

Is seems to be an implementation of the Cesar chiffre.

Comment: Java characters are not limited to ASCII (which has only 128 characters). Java uses Unicode.

Comment: C characters aren't either.

Answer (score 0):

A char is a two-bytes unsigned integer in Java. `'c'` is a more readable way (when dealing with characters) of saying 99, because the Unicode value of the character `'c'` is 99.

So if your c variable is the character `'c'`, its value is 99. The value of `'a'` being 97, `'c' - 'a'` is equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is technically a numeric type - it uses the Unicode codepoint for the character as its data value. Subtracting `'a'` from 'c' would give the position of 'c' in the alphabet. `%=26` sets the letter to the remainder that occurs when it is divided by 26. Basically, this method uses a Caesar cipher to shift each letter by `shift` places.

Comment: Thanks!! I thought something like this but it wasn't really explained in my course book.

Comment: `char` holds a UTF-16 code-unit. UTF-16 might use one or two code-units to represent a Unicode character. The Character class is filled with methods that use `int` instead of `char`. The String class has additional methods that deal with codepoints as `int` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

when using c-'a', it means that you subtract the ASCII code number of the symbol "a" from the symbol "c".
http://www.asciitable.com/
you can see that every symbol has its own ascii number. From example
       ASCII of "c" = 99
       ASCII of "a" = 97
so c-a = 2.

Comment: `c` is the name of a variable in this case, not a `char` literal.